# select specific children from a nested list jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to solve this problem- I  would like to select the first children of the LI "sally", currently my solution is selecting the first list 
("car", "boat", "bike"), but also selecting the next list("red","green", "blue")... How can I solve this so that only the first list i.e. ("car", "boat", "bike") is selected?

```
<h2>Select specific children from a nested list.</h2>
    <p>Select the only the first children of the LI "Sally".</p>
    <div id="content2">
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>Some Text</p>
                <p>Some More Text</p>
                <div>Random Div</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Bob</li>
                    <li>Sally</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Car</li>
                            <li>Boat</li>
                            <li>Bike
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Red</li>
                                    <li>Green</li>
                                    <li>Blue</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Larry</li>
                    <li>Mo</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My current solution is...

```
$("div#content2 > div > div > ul > ul > li").css("color", "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do this by changing class and using css instead.

Would also suggest you use some attributes like id or class on the `<ul>` to simplify the selector needed

```js
$("#content2 > div > div > ul > li > ul > li").addClass('red')
```

```css
li,
li.red li {
  color: black
}
li.red,
li.red li.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<div id="content2">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some More Text</p>
      <div>Random Div</div>
      <ul>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Sally
          <ul>
            <li>Car</li>
            <li>Boat</li>
            <li>Bike
              <ul>
                <li>Red</li>
                <li>Green</li>
                <li>Blue</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Larry</li>
        <li>Mo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use two lines, rather than one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('div#content2 li li').css('color', 'red');
$('div#content2 li li li').css('color', 'black');

});
```

---

**N.B.** Your markup should read:

```
<li>Sally
    <ul>
```

not:

```
<li>Sally</li>
    <ul>
```